# Celery concurrency with celery beat

Tags: python, celery, python-multiprocessing, django-celery, django-celery-beat

I use celery worker with parameter concurrency equals 20. And also I launch `celery-beat`. But every periodic task from `celery-beat` goes on every `celery` worker (in my situation on 20 workers, and periodic task is done 20 times). What can I do? I want produce periodic task one time every 60 seconds. And another tasks use for another purpose.

My launches:

```
$ celery -A config worker -l info -c 20 --pool=prefork
$ celery -A config beat -l info
```

I saw `celery` routing, but I want more beautiful solution. Also I look for more beautiful solution.

Comment: can you elaborate on why you are using `prefork`? what's your broker? can you share your beat's call to the periodic task? can you share any special celery configuration that you set?